# Bolding specific lines in textbox and indenting to the right side

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, textbox, formatting

I am trying to bold just certain lines in the textbox, not all of the output.  And also am trying to pad a couple of lines all the way to the far right of the textbox, not all of the lines, to make it look cleaner.

I am trying to bold all of the (`txtBoxCourse` textboxes) and trying to indent all of the (`txtBoxGrades` textboxes) to the right.

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    Dim semester, Newline As String
    Dim totalGPA As Double = QualityPoints / txtBoxTotalHours.Text

    Newline = System.Environment.NewLine
    semester = CStr(txtBoxResults.Text)
    txtBoxTotalGPA.Text = CStr(totalGPA)
    txtBoxTotalGPA.Text = Math.Round(totalGPA, 3)

    If radButtonFall.Checked Then
        semester = "Fall"
    ElseIf radButtonSpring.Checked Then
        semester = "Spring"
    ElseIf radButtonSummer.Checked Then
        semester = "Summer"
    End If


    txtBoxResults.Text = (semester & " " & "Semester : ")
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & " ")
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & " ")
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & "Total Hours : " & txtBoxTotalHours.Text)
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & " ")
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & "Total Qualit Points : " & txtBoxTotalQualityPoints.Text)
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & " ")
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & "Total " & semester & " " & "GPA : " & txtBoxTotalGPA.Text)
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & " ")
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & " ")
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & "Enrolled Courses : ")
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & " ")
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & txtBoxCourse1.Text & "     " & txtBoxGrade1.Text)
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & " ")
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & txtBoxCourse2.Text & "     " & txtBoxGrade2.Text)
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & " ")
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & txtBoxCourse3.Text & "     " & txtBoxGrade3.Text)
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & " ")
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & txtBoxCourse4.Text & "     " & txtBoxGrade4.Text)
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & " ")
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & txtBoxCourse5.Text & "     " & txtBoxGrade5.Text)
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & " ")
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & txtBoxCourse6.Text & "     " & txtBoxGrade6.Text)
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & " ")
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & txtBoxCourse7.Text & "     " & txtBoxGrade7.Text)
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & " ")
    txtBoxResults.Text = (txtBoxResults.Text & Newline & txtBoxCourse8.Text & "     " & txtBoxGrade8.Text)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to bold just certain lines in the textbox, not all of the output.

Unfortunately, the TextBox control does not support formatted text. You can change the font, making it bold if you desire, but then *all* of the text will be bold. There is no way to make only *some* of the text bold.

You'll see the same limitations in the Windows Notepad, which is just a TextBox control that has a menu attached to it to support loading and saving files. You can change the font that Notepad uses, but it's a one-size-fits-all affair. There's no way to apply conditional formatting to specific lines or characters.

If you need to support conditional formatting, you will need to switch to a [RichTextBox control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) instead. This is basically what Wordpad uses, and it explains why Wordpad is more like a true word processor than Notepad. Naturally, that power comes at a bit of a usability expense: it's more trouble to work with a RichTextBox control than a simple TextBox control in your code.

> And also am trying to pad a couple of lines all the way to the far right of the textbox, not all of the lines, to make it look cleaner.

This is…sort of possible, although it's not pretty. Assuming that your form (or at least the textbox control) is not resizable, and that the font will never change, you can calculate the number of spaces required to pad the text out to the far right of the textbox and insert that exact number.

To do this, you'll use the [`TextRenderer.MeasureText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext.aspx) method. [The simplest overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4xdbe66.aspx) will tell you the number of pixels that a particular string of text will take up when drawn in the specified font (the one used by your text box). You'll use that information, subtract it from the [client area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.clientsize.aspx) of your text box control, and then pad the string (using, e.g. [`String.PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk6ydzx.aspx)) with the required number of spaces.

Ugh! What a pain! And obviously this will need to be recalculated each time the text is changed. And scroll bars will also wreck your careful layout, so even a change in the number of vertical lines can require a recomputation.

If you really need to create some visual distinction and you can't switch to a different control, just insert a tab at the beginning of the lines to indent them. In VB.NET, you use the constant `vbTab` to insert a tab into a string; e.g., `myTextBox.Text = vbTab & "Some text"`

But from reading your sample code, it looks like to me that you're trying to display some formatted results of a calculation. You really don't need or want a text control for that at all! The only time you need a text control (like a TextBox or a RichTextBox) is when you need to support user input. If you're calculating the output, you probably aren't supporting input in the same place. Therefore, why not try using a ListBox or ListView control instead? This handles all of the multi-line layout and formatting stuff for you, which would make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use Panel to contain controls, and if you still want to use textbox (i think its better to use label) , add them as control in the Panel. Like below:

```
    'create textbox
    Dim tx, tx2 As New TextBox

    'set font style, location, and text
    tx.Font = New System.Drawing.Font(tx.Font, FontStyle.Bold)        
    tx2.Font = tx.Font
    tx2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(tx.Location.X, tx.Location.Y + 25)
    tx.text = "here"
    tx2.text = "here"

    'add them into Panel
    Panel1.Controls.Add(tx)
    Panel1.Controls.Add(tx2)
```

You can modify tx's text, font, and etc.

Comment: Why in the world would you add TextBox controls to a ListBox control? This is not the correct way to use a ListBox. A ListBox is *not* a container control. It's not designed to hold other controls. If you want that behavior, you need to use one of the container controls, like a Panel, TableLayoutPanel, or FlowLayoutPanel.